# iPad Form Sheet Flip Left To Right

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a view sized as a form sheet and displayed modal.  How can I transition this view to another form sheet using the flip left to right transition?

Comment: I assume you've already tried adding another modal segue with flip transition from the modal displayed view?

Comment: Yep. It didn't work - it doesn't transition properly and also the flip is top to bottom.

Comment: I imagine this is due to how a form sheet animation works. Since it's dimming the background and disabling interaction when presenting I'm not sure this is even possible. Although, creating the animation yourself shouldn't be that difficult to do.

Comment: That's what I need to know how to do.